# Converting from NaiveDateTime to DateTime<Local>

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

Rust's `chrono` has been very frustrating to work with as it makes converting from timezones very difficult.

For example: my user inputs a string. I parse this into a naive date time using `NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str`. Now I would like to convert this into a `DateTime<Local>`.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find out how to do so. Using `Local::From` doesn't work. Using `DateTime<Local>::from()` doesn't work either. Neither structs have methods to convert from a `NaiveDateTime`, and `NaiveDateTime` doesn't have methods to convert into `Local`.

Yet, we can do things like this: `someLocalDateTime.date().and_time(some_naive_time)`. So why can't we just do `Local::new(some_naive_date_time)`?

Additionally, why can't we skip fields in the parsing? I don't need seconds and I don't need year. In order to assume the current year and 0 seconds, I have to manually write parsing code and construct the datetime from ymd hms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This functionality is provided by [the `chrono::offset::TimeZone` trait](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.11/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html). Specifically, the method [`TimeZone::from_local_datetime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.11/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html#method.from_local_datetime) is almost precisely what you're looking for.

```rust
use chrono::{offset::TimeZone, DateTime, Local, NaiveDateTime};

fn main() {
    let naive = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("2020-11-12T5:52:46", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").unwrap();
    let date_time: DateTime<Local> = Local.from_local_datetime(&naive).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", date_time);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=778daa9d67b47ae9e04712857e0fb12f)

---

As for the other question about parsing with assumptions, I'm not sure if the tools exist yet. It would be cool if `ParseResult` allowed you to manually set specific values before unwrapping (or what have you) the result.

One idea that lets you still use `chrono`'s parser is to manually add the extra fields to the parse string.

For example:

```rust
use chrono::{offset::TimeZone, DateTime, Datelike, Local, NaiveDateTime};

fn main() {
    let time_string = "11-12T5:52"; // no year or seconds
    let current_year = Local::now().year();
    let modified_time_string = format!("{}&{}:{}", time_string, current_year, 0);

    let naive = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(&modified_time_string, "%m-%dT%H:%M&%Y:%S").unwrap();
    let date_time: DateTime<Local> = Local.from_local_datetime(&naive).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", date_time); // prints (as of 2020) 2020-11-12T05:52:00+00:00
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0307004f780f9565e2d4483f20f1bab6)